# add meta keywords to category list html page output

Tags: magento

is it somehow possible to echo the category metakeywords on the category list view below the produkt list?

I tried somethink like this in the file template/catalog/catalog/product/list.phtml:

```
<?php echo $_category->getMetaKeywords(); ?>
```

but it doesn't output anything. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get any output because $_category variable is not initialized in template/catalog/catalog/product/list.phtml. The following code shall work:

```
<?php

$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
echo $_category->getMetaKeywords();

?>
```